# C++ equation returns -nan(ind)

Tags: c++

So I'm writing code to semi-automatically solve (in)direct proportional questions using two values that are always given at the start. It's returning a -nan(ind) error so I'm hopefully seeking for someone to help. Thank you in advance, your help is always appreciated no matter how small it is.
I understand nan is not a number but it's just being irritating to fix this, not asking for someone to feed me the fix but if you'd like to you may - I'm looking to find a fix so that in the future I wouldn't be as clueless when it comes to an issue like this.

```
#include "Prop.h"

float c, d, k;

std::string prop::getinput(std::string obj) {
    std::getline(std::cin, obj);
}

float prop::storefloat(float inp) {
    std::cin >> inp;
    return 1;
}

int prop::printarr(float arr[]) {
    std::copy(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, "\n"));
}

int prop::compare(int com, int pare) {
    if (com && pare <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
}

void prop::direct(float a, float b, float constant) {
    constant = DIRECTfindconstant(a, b);
    printf("%d\n", constant);
    c = ((constant) * (b));
    printf("%d\n", c);
    d = ((b) / (constant));
    printf("%d\n", d);
    std::cout << "Constant : " << constant << "\nDominant algebraic letter : " << c << "\nSecond Letter : " << d << "\n";
}

float prop::completedirect(float a, float b, float c) {
    compare(a, b);
    direct(a, b, c);
    return 0;
}

float prop::DIRECTfindconstant(float a, float b) {
    //k on bottom right, a ontop, b on bottom right
    float k = ((a) / (b));

    return k;
}
float prop::INDIRECTfindconstant(float a, float b) {
    //k ontop, a on bottom left, b on bottom right
    float k = a * b;
    return k;
}


void prop::caseinput(int inp, float val, float val2) {
    switch (inp) {
    case Prop::proportionality::direct: {
        float constant = DIRECTfindconstant(val, val2);
        printf("%d\n", constant);
        printf("%d", val);
        printf("%d", val2);
        completedirect(val, val2, constant);
        break;
    };
    default:
        break;
    }
}
//prop.cpp
int main()
{
    std::cin >> test;
    pro->storefloat(a);
    pro->storefloat(b);
    pro->caseinput(test, a, b);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it seems my storefloat wasn't working, I switched it to std::cin alone and it started to function.

Comment: `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` that's wrong, since `arr` is a pointer. leave C-style arrays alone and use std::vector instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the relevant part:

```
float prop::storefloat(float inp) {
    std::cin >> inp;
    return 1;
}
```

This is pass-by-value, as your book should tell you. You can change the local `inp`, but it does not affect the caller. The return value `1` is pointless here, while return values are the logical way to return a value to the caller.